# advanced text formatting with wand (magickwand)

Tags: python, imagemagick, magickwand, wand

While creating images with formatted annotations i have found image magick ability to render html like formatted text (pango http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#pango ).

Further investigation showed that there is no pango functionality implemented in wand, but that is easy to implement if magickwand has this ability as wand just uses wraps it.

So the question is: how to use pango with magickwand if it's possible 
Or is there any other way to render formatted text (for example different colors and font weights of some words in the middle of text) without calculating positions and rendering all different formats separately?